# Invariant Violation when trying to render array of table row elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React and I'm trying to render a table that will be dynamic in the number of rows depending on the result size.

However I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled Rejection Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as
>   React child (found: objects with keys {name}). If you meant to render
>   a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object
>   using createFragment(object).

I have the following code and loop in the render function :

```
let result = this.props.result.exactMatches;
var rows = [];
for(var i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
   rows.push(
      <tr>
         <td width="50%"> result[i].name </td>
         <td width="50%"> result[i].position </td>
      </tr>
   );  
}
```

Then in the return jsx element I have the following div element:

```
<div>
<table style={{width:'100%'}}>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <th width="50%"> Name </th>
      <th width="50%"> Position </th>
    </tr>
    {rows}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Share please your `exactMatches ` object

Answer (score 1):

The error log is pretty self explanatory but lets go through it carefully.

> Objects are not valid as React child

That pretty much means that React does not know to render an array of React components in the form you are providing it.

> If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object)

I would suggest going through [createFragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-fragment.html) documentation. The issue described is similar yours.

The React rendering pipeline uses a couple of heuristics to improve performance. One of them requires the developer to distinguish adjacent elements of the same type (e.g. `<tr />`) using a unique `key` property in each one of them.

Onto the solution itself, I would suggest embracing a more functional programming approach. [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a method used on arrays. Think of it as turn this array of cats into an array of dogs but let me show you how.

In your case, you want to turn an array of matches called `exactMatches` into rows of a table, and thats what we are going to do.

```
<div>
<table style={{width:'100%'}}>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <th width="50%"> Name </th>
      <th width="50%"> Position </th>
    </tr>
    this.props.result.exactMatches.map((match, index) => (
      <tr key={`row-${match.name}-${index}`}>
         <td width="50%">match.name</td>
         <td width="50%">match.position</td>
      </tr>
    ))
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not returning the JSX in your map function.

Comment: Good catch! Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do it.

```
let result = this.props.result.exactMatches;
var rows = [];
for(var i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
   rows.push(
           {name: result[i].name , position:result[i].position}
   );  
}
```

and render it like this.

```
<div>
<table style={{width:'100%'}}>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
      <th width="50%"> Name </th>
      <th width="50%"> Position </th>
    </tr>
    {rows.map((rowData, index) =>{
    return  <tr key=`results-row-${rowData.name}-${index}`>
         <td width="50%"> {rowData.name} </td>
         <td width="50%"> {rowData.position} </td>
      </tr>
    })}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to return the JSX in your `rows.map` function. And the `key` prop for each `tr` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is a correct way:

<div>
<table style={{width:'100%'}}>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th width="50%"> Name </th>
    <th width="50%"> Position </th>
  </tr>
  {this.props.exactMatches.map((item, i) => <tr key={i}>
    <td width="50%"> {item.name }</td>
    <td width="50%"> {item.position} </td>
  </tr>)}
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Pay attention for keys, if you have something unique value in each entity you can use it.